# Unpredictable behaviour of Screen Settings in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4, windows-10

I can set any usable screen settings in Fallout 4 on my Windows 10.

Windowed mode can be stuck

[image]

and it can be unable to turn it off.

Next run it can be available, but resolution drop down can be empty

[image]

It is impossible to run Fallout in any combination. It can either run highly distorted and corrupted (see menu background):

[image]

or it can run partially occupying the desktop

[image]

Is it possible to get something consistent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a 21:9 monitor, and Fallout 4 doesn't support that. You'll need to use the mod [TruBy9 Ultrawide](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/24630) to allow it to work with this monitor aspect ratio, and manually set the `isize W` and `isize H` in (default location)`Documents/My Games/Fallout 4/falloutprefs.ini` to 3440x1440. Then keep in mind that any time you change your graphics settings you'll need to go back in and change the resolution in the ini.